# Website not displaying correctly in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

For some reason the website I built will display correctly in Chrome, Firefox and IE10 but in IE9 it displays incorrectly. It won't display the background and it is all off alignment. Does anyone have any ideas?

Website: http://www.thefishonthedome.com

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the HTML comment before the open  tag at the top and replacing it with a `<!doctype html>` declaration? Your page is running in Quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS to define the width, try to define it in HTML itself.

Comment: It has been fixed. Thanks Eric and Micro.Pravi for your responses! Have a great day.